# How to list tables in wordpress plugin development?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I want to show all table names in my plugin development. I know how to do that in core PHP.

I am trying like this:

```
$mytables=$wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLES");
 foreach ($mytables as $mytable)
            {
              echo $mytable;
            }
```

Comment: The result of a query is usually an array of rows where each row is an array of fields. You've got to nest two foreach loops. But that's no difference to plain PHP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you should use nested foreach loops.

```
global $wpdb;
$mytables=$wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLES");
foreach ($mytables as $mytable)
{
    foreach ($mytable as $t) 
    {       
        echo $t . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to know the name of your database, because `SHOW TABLES` will create the column name "Tables_in_" (without < and > of course).

Answer (score 0):

There is a native function in WordPress for that: wpdb::tables( string $scope = 'all', bool $prefix = true, int $blog_id ). See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/tables/ for details ;-)

Answer (score -2):

check the following function to get list of tables

```
    $mytables=$wpdb->get_results("SHOW TABLES FROM ".$wpdb->dbname);

    foreach ($mytables as $mytable)
    {
        echo($mytable->Tables_in_wordpress).'<br/>';
    }
    die;
```

Comment: Add global $wpdb; before this function.